# Comparar datas de meses diferentes

Tags: php

Boas,

Estou a utilizar o seguinte codigo para calcular se uma data é inferior à outra :

```
$dferiasinicial =date("d/m/Y",strtotime($_POST['dferiasinicial']));
$da = date("d/m/Y");

if($dferiasinicial <= $da){

return true;
else{
return false;
}
```

Se o valor de `$dferiasinicial` for 16/05/2019 e o valor de `$da` for 16/04/2019 a função vai me retornar false porque está apenas a ter em conta os dias.

Alguem me consegue explicar porquê e/ou dar-me uma solução?

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Tenta algo deste género

```
$dferiasinicial->diff($da)->d
```